# lombok @Data and @Getter don't give getter function

Tags: java, lombok

I am using a simple code:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;

@Data
public class MyClass {
    @Getter
    String id;

    public MyClass(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

but when I instantiate that class, I don't have the getId() method though I added getter and Data

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: @baklarz2048 Intij

Comment: Do you have [IntelliJ Lombok plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok) installed? Here are [the instructions](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij)

Comment: Also make sure you have annotations turned on

Comment: If you are using Eclipse this might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsFPXkYDb-s

Answer (score 1):

Code is ok. Problem is the IDE configuration.

idea:

- enable annotation processing
- install lombok plugin

https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

Answer (score 0):

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
class MyClass {
    private String id;
    MyClass(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class InitialMyClass {
    String initialId() {
        String id = "123";
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(id);
        return myClass.getId();
    }
}
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

I have also added lombok to my IDE. I used STS and to use lombok I have added lombok jar to my project then double clicked on the lombok jar which opened the configuration window there I have just provided my IDE path(from my local machine) to lombok and then just restarted the application and it worked.

You can try the same.

Answer (score 0):

For linux user(i have linux mint vanessa)

- follow instuction here: https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide
  after you download the jar file, run the jar by this command(example im using version 1.18.24):

  ```bash
  java -jar lombok-1.18.24.jar
  ```

  by default, the program will search the eclipse installation automatically. But if the program failed, you can search the eclipse manually.
- If you failed to search the eclipse manually, you can reinstall it from official installer here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer, so you will need to download `tar.gz` file.
- Extract and run the installer file, then you will able to manually set the eclipse installation location.
- Next, follow again the instruction from baeldung site.